# gwt widget that contain another widget: 2 different clickhandlers

Tags: java, gwt, widget

I'm studying the GWT framework and I'm trying to create a custom widget: this widget is a button that contain inside a menu of operations.

if you click in the area of the triangle I want a menu with some options (that are possible operations) and if I click in the other parts of the buttons I want that the operation is the first from the list.
I have put a ListBox widget inside a Button widget and I want 2 different clickListener. The problem is that the listener of the listBox inside the button don't work.
Do you know why?

Following the code

public class MyClass extends Composite {

```
private ListBox options;
private Button saveButton;
private HorizontalPanel savePanel;
private int indexHandler;

public MyClass(String label, List<String> operationList, final List<Command> commandList) {

    savePanel = new HorizontalPanel();
    initWidget(savePanel);

    options = new ListBox();
    saveButton = new Button(label);


    for(String operation : operationList){
        options.addItem(operation);
    }

    options.sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK);

    options.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

            System.out.println("Test1");
            indexHandler = options.getSelectedIndex();
            commandList.get(indexHandler).execute();
            options.setItemSelected(0, true);
        }
    });

    saveButton.getElement().appendChild(options.getElement());

    saveButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

            System.out.println("Test2");

            commandList.get(0).execute();
            options.setItemSelected(0, true);

        } 

    });

    savePanel.add(saveButton);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Don't use ClickHandler on the ListBox. Use ChangeHandler instead.

Also, I don't think you need to mess with Elements here. Simply add your Button widget and your ListBox widget to a container (i.e. some panel). You can add button on top of ListBox, if you want.

Comment: Hi Andrei, thank for your reply. I've tried the changeHandler instead the clickHandler, but is not executed (I tried even in debug mode to be sure). In this way it seems that all the handlers assigned to the internal widget are deleted (or maybe overwritten).
I've tried to add the widgets side by side, but grafically is not what I want.

Comment: Your handler disappears when you do .getElement().appeandChild(). You don't need to add widgets side by side, you can add one on top of the other, so only a button is visible. Use CSS or a panel to achieve this effect.